# Single-pass streaming quantile estimation using moments

Tags: ds.algorithms, data-streams, streaming-algorithms, streaming

Is it possible to estimate within $\epsilon$ the quantiles of a set of integers $\{x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n\}$ given only the values $\sum x_i^0,\sum x_i^1, \sum x_i^2, \dots, \sum x_i^{f(n)}$ where $f \in o(n)$? If so, what is the most slowly growing $f$ that will suffice?

By "estimate the quantiles", I mean:

> ... for any given rank $r$, an $\epsilon$-approximate quantile summary returns a value whose rank $r'$ is guaranteed to be within the interval $[r - \epsilon n, r + \epsilon n]$.

following ["Space-Efficient Online Computation of Quantile
Summaries", by Greenwald and Khanna](http://infolab.stanford.edu/~datar/courses/cs361a/papers/quantiles.pdf).

I'm also interested in whether this is possible with non-integer, non-consecutive moments, so sets of values like $\sum x_i^{-1/2}, \sum x_i^\pi$ are also of interest.

I am more interested in deterministic algorithms than randomized ones.

Comment: Yes. It was $N$ in the paper cited. Fixed.

Comment: Do you have a function $f$ that always suffices?  Does it not have to depend on $\epsilon$?

Comment: $f(n) = n$ is sufficient, I believe, by https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/27952/solving-a-system-of-sums-of-powers-polynomials

Comment: And yes, presumably it will depend on $\epsilon$.

Comment: I'm skeptical that any $f=o(n)$ will suffice.  Consider estimating the median.  For $f=1$, compare the sequence $0,0,0,\dots,0,x$ to $y,\dots,y$ where $y=x/n$; they're indistinguishable from the values you're given, but have very different medians.  For $f=2$, compare the sequence $0,0,0,\dots,0,x$ to $y,y,\dots,y,z$ where $x=ny/2$ and $z=-ny/2$; the same thing happens.  I suspect this will generalize to larger $f$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gan et al. address this in [Moment-Based Quantile Sketches for Efficient High Cardinality Aggregation Queries](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1803.01969.pdf). The answers are rather nuanced.